# $form->get('element') in ZF2 returns NULL

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a form for adding user.
The problem is: I recieve NULL when trying to get the form element from my Controller.
Here is the form:

```
public function __cunstruct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('user');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'Id',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'id',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        'name' => 'IsCreate',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'false'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'Username',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'username'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name'
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'Password',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'password'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'ConfirmPassword',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'password'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Confirm password'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'TypeId',
        'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Type'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'valut' => 'Create',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
        )
    ));
}
```

And here is Controller example:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new AddUserForm();
    var_dump($form);
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    var_dump($form->get('TypeId'));
}
```

In `var_dump($form)` I recieve array, but there is no data:

```
object(WebAdmin\Form\EditUserForm)#306 (27) { ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["method"]=> string(4) "POST" } ["bindAs":protected]=> int(17) ["bindOnValidate":protected]=> int(0) ["baseFieldset":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> NULL ["filter":protected]=> NULL ["useInputFilterDefaults":protected]=> bool(true) ["hasAddedInputFilterDefaults":protected]=> bool(false) ["hasValidated":protected]=> bool(false) ["isValid":protected]=> bool(false) ["isPrepared":protected]=> bool(false) ["preferFormInputFilter":protected]=> bool(false) ["wrapElements":protected]=> bool(false) ["validationGroup":protected]=> NULL ["factory":protected]=> NULL ["byName":protected]=> array(0) { } ["elements":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fieldsets":protected]=> array(0) { } ["messages":protected]=> array(0) { } ["iterator":protected]=> object(Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue)#307 (3) { ["queueClass":protected]=> string(28) "Zend\Stdlib\SplPriorityQueue" ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queue":protected]=> NULL } ["hydrator":protected]=> NULL ["object":protected]=> NULL ["useAsBaseFieldset":protected]=> bool(false) ["label":protected]=> NULL ["labelAttributes":protected]=> NULL ["options":protected]=> array(0) { } ["value":protected]=> NULL }
```

In `var_dump($form->get('TypeId'))` I recieve just NULL.

Therefore when I am trying to add the user, I have an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /controller_path/ on line 72
```

The line is: `$form->get('TypeId')->setAttribute('options', $options);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the constructor; meaning the elements are never added on construct as the method would not be called.

```
 public function __cunstruct($name = null)
```

Should be

```
 public function __construct($name = null)
```

With that said @MaiKay's answer suggesting use of the [`FormElementManager`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements) is really what you should be doing.

You will also then be able to move the adding of elements to the `init()` method which is called when you get the form using `$formElementManager->get('Module\Form\Foo')`

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use the [FormElementManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html) to recieve your form.

for example

```
<?php
$sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get('\Application\Form\MyForm');
return array('form' => $form);
```